# Can I connect a WAMS to both a Windows Store app AND a WP8 app?

Tags: azure, windows-8, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I just created my first WAMS (pipe down - no hysteria, please).

When I'm in the WAMS management area, though, it wants me to "Choose Platform," with the options of "Windows Store", "Windows Phone 8", and "IOS" (meh).

I want to choose the first *two* platforms, not just one of them. Is that possible, or will I need to create one for my Windows store app, and another one for my WP8 app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That screen is somewhat misleading, you only need one service that's accessible from any platform.  The context of "Choose Platform" here is to create a quick-start app (note the graphic above with the text "Let's connect it to an app") that will use that service.  You can select any (or all, on multiple visits) of the three platforms and get boiler plate code to show you how use WAMS from those specific platforms, but the service you're targeting is the same.